# How can I compute a vector with means of another one?

Tags: matlab, mean

I have a vector `A` with 400 values, and I need another vector `B` with 100 values, where every value is the mean of the corresponding 4 values in `A`. For example, the first value of `B` would be the mean of the 1st-4th values of `A`, the second value of B would be the mean of the 5th-8th values of `A`, and so on. How can I do this in MATLAB?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `A` is your 400x1 vector, you can [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) it into a matrix with columns of four, and apply [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html).

```
A_means = mean(reshape(A(:), 4, []));
```

This works because `mean` operates along columns, if not specified otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution.

I have expanded it a bit so it will also work if the vector is not an exact multiple of four:

```
A = 1:399;

B = NaN(4,ceil(length(A)/4));
B(1:length(A))=A;
nanmean(B)
```